# What is the best way to play a video located on another computer in LAN?

Tags: windows, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I've got a desktop with a 500GB harddisc with some movies. I would like to play a video from it on my laptop which has only 64GB SSD and is in another room, but on the same LAN.

For now both computers run on Windows so I have a shared folder set on the desktop, which I connect to from my laptop. Then I just start playing the video in VLC from my laptop. The problem is that the video sometimes freeze for a few sec to load a new bunch of data.

Is there some option to either set the cache (for VLC) bigger or should I use some different protocol to send video over LAN to have it play smoother (streaming?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VLC you can setup a custom cache value by selection "Open (advanced)" from the Media menu.  In the dialog that opens select the media you want to play then click on the "Show more options" checkbox in the bottom left.  This will expose additional options, one of which is "Caching."

Answer (score 1):

Real Time Streaming Protocol instead should be used as well as taking into account data rates over 802.11 wireless which is slower than Ethernet.

Have a look at http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html#id349956 firstly.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've tried that, but the problem is I would like to select the videos, download subtitles and so on from the laptop. And that is not easily possible (I can use remote desktop, but that's a little bit too much).

Comment: Okay then heavyd’s response is probably best for you then, I wouldn’t recommend RDC.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldnt you just copy it over, or copy 5 or 6 over and then watch them and toss them when done?  The last thing I would want when watching a movie would be to have to diagnose the net, or have to reposition the adapter to get better speeds.

even if you started with 1 all there, then started copying another across while watching that one.  Mabey I just dont watch enough YouTube :-) to think that streaming is all that, when a SD card alone is enough to play it for real.